# Restricting SSH login by IP address on Debian

Tags: ssh

I want to allow SSH logins only from 3 IP addresses: 111.111.111.111 and 222.222.222.222 and 333.333.333.333. I know, I have to edit /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny files.

My question is about the content of these files. I have seen different variants:

**# /etc/hosts.allow**

Variant 1:

```
sshd: 111.111.111
sshd: 222.222.222
sshd: 333.333.333
```

Variant 2:

```
sshd: 111.111.111, 222.222.222, 333.333.333
```

Variant 3: (without commas):

```
sshd: 111.111.111 222.222.222 333.333.333
```

Variant 4 (with sshdfwd-X11):

```
sshd,sshdfwd-X11: 111.111.111 222.222.222 333.333.333
```

**/etc/hosts.deny**

Variant 1:

```
sshd: ALL
```

Variant2:

```
sshd,sshdfwd-X11:ALL
```

Which is the correct one? I am afraid to lock me out. Thanks.

Comment: Don't log out of the machine until you 100% confirm the configuration is working as intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do this personally in the `sshd_config` using `AllowUsers`.

```
AllowUsers = *@111.111.111.111, *@222.222.222.222, *@333.333.333.333
```

To me, that keeps all the config in the place associated with the application you're controlling.  There's always more than one way to skin a cat with UNIX, but if the tool offers a specific control mechanism I tend to prefer that over anything else (it's *usually* more portable).

When making changes to anything in relation to remote access,

1. always have multiple sessions on the server already
2. make the changes from within a screen or tmux session so you can reconnect to it if you lose connection
3. try and make the changes from a non-ssh console if possible

I find that as long as you've got a few remote sessions already, you'll be fine.  Changing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and recycling SSH does not disconnect any existing sessions.

Although I appreciate that doesn't answer your specific question.  I believe [Jeff's answer does](https://serverfault.com/a/391445/84542) (in that all those variants are valid if you use `/etc/hosts.deny` or `/etc/hosts.allow`).

Comment: I think it's better to use the options and tools that ssh gives u than using external applications such as iptables (iptables would be nice also).

Comment: thanks EightBitTony. I like your solution and going to try it. I was thinking that in AllowUsers I must specify only usenames, not IPs.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it is my preference to implement rules like this using `iptables`.

As far as the correct variant, all of those should work. The [relevant man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.allow) (thanks for catching this Oliver) says using blanks or commas is acceptable. It also does go on to discuss that any match of `daemon: client` will count and that multiple clients can be listed to a line, and multiple entries for a daemon will all be evaluated.

Comment: `List elements should be separated by blanks and/or commas.`